# How to add Classname as select when my home page as "www.example.com"?

Tags: php, .htaccess, menu, redirect

I am working in PHP website. I am having menu with select option on corresponding pages. Here are my code :

### PHP

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$page = ltrim(str_replace("/", "", dirname($path)."/".basename($path, '.php')),"/");
?>

<div id="navbar-collapse-grid" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li><a href="<?php echo SITE_PATH; ?>" <?php echo ($path == "/index.php") ? 'class="select"' : ''; ?>>Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="<?php echo SITE_PATH; ?>about/overview.php" <?php echo ($path == "/about/overview.php") ? 'class="select"' : ''; ?>>About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Everything is work fine. If my url as "www.example.com/index.php", Home as SELECT. "www.example.com/about/overview.php", then About SELECT.

1) My Question is how to write code or how to check my path as "www.example.com" instead of "www.example.com/index.php". Because, all you know, i need a home page link as "www.example.com/" and not as "www.example.com/index.php"

2) How to redirect this as in .htaccess file and where to put and how to conect this .htaccess file.

Comment: https://github.com/phanan/htaccess, has a lot of .htacess snippets

Comment: In your first question, Where do you want to check `www.example.com` in PHP or .htaccess?